# The iOS App Store now supports downloading code on the fly. How do I implement this?

Tags: ios, security, app-store, ios11, xcode9

I want to implement this feature as described in the [App Store terms:](http://www.appstorereviewguidelineshistory.com/articles/2017-06-08-new-rules-following-wwdc-2017/)

[image]

What interfaces, delegates, protocols, etc, must I implement to comply with the above requirement?  (Yes I'm creating a development and education app)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my interactions with Apple's review process, this guideline won't have code-level compliance mechanisms. You should ensure that the intended function of your app is well known to Apple. You probably shouldn't download code without user interaction. This guideline is to prevent people from changing the function of the an app after it has been reviewed, which [bypasses App Store review](https://developer.apple.com/terms/) and could potentially have malicious intent (but usually doesn't).

In addition to section **2.5.2** of the App Store Review Guidelines, this topic is covered in section **3.3.2** of the [Apple Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/terms/).

> An Application that is a programming environment intended for use in
>   learning how to program may download and run executable code so long
>   as the following requirements are met: (i) no more than 80 percent of
>   the Application’s viewing area or screen may be taken over with
>   executable code, except as otherwise permitted in the Documentation,
>   (ii) the Application must present a reasonably conspicuous indicator
>   to the user within the Application to indicate that the user is in a
>   programming environment, (iii) the Application must not create a store
>   or storefront for other code or applications, and (iv) the source code
>   provided by the Application must be completely viewable and editable
>   by the user (e.g., no pre-compiled libraries or frameworks may be
>   included with the code downloaded).